# Flex wrap separated with line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to separate two columns with a vertical line. I don't want that extra line on the left of the first seven divs, like in my current code.

Edit: The flexbox is constantly changing, because the divs are being rendered. The code I used below is a simplified version

What I have so far:

```css
.flexbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div class="wrap"><span>First item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Second item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Third item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Fourth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Fifth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Sixth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Seventh item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Eigth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Nineth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>tenth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Eleventh item</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the height of `.flexbox` change?

Comment: Yes, its constantly changing, because the divs are being rendered. The code I used above is a simplified version.

Comment: Ok, I think you should update your question to include that as it is important information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cover the first line with a pseudo element on the container. This will work with any height and any number of elements.

```css
.flexbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.flexbox:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="wrap"><span>First item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Second item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Third item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Fourth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Fifth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Sixth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Seventh item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Eigth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Nineth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>tenth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Eleventh item</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Nice clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

> I **don't** want that extra line on the left of the **first seven** divs, like in my current code.

Use an `nth-child` selector to NOT select the first seven items:

```css
.flexbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexbox div:nth-child(n+8) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="wrap"><span>First item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Second item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Third item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Fourth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Fifth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Sixth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Seventh item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Eigth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Nineth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>tenth item</span></div>
  <div class="wrap"><span>Eleventh item</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another class

```css
.flexbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.wrap1 {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
 <div class="wrap"><span>First item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Second item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Third item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Fourth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Fifth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Sixth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap"><span>Seventh item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap wrap1"><span>Eigth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap wrap1"><span>Nineth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap wrap1"><span>tenth item</span></div>
 <div class="wrap wrap1"><span>Eleventh item</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that my divs are being rendered from a database (which will most likely change). I cant go through all divs manually to give them another class, because which is now my 3rd div, might be the 11th next week.

Comment: @codenoob sorry when i originally answered i did not see it specify the elements would change. looks like others have updated to accommodate this already. Let me know if you'd like me to update mine further.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `.flexbox` and use a negative margin to visually hide the left vertical line.

```css
.container {
  padding-left: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexbox {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="wrap"><span>First item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Second item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Third item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Fourth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Fifth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Sixth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Seventh item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Eigth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Nineth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>tenth item</span></div>
    <div class="wrap"><span>Eleventh item</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```